# Horde3D not rendering to GLFW window in OS X

Tags: c++, macos, glfw

I'm an experienced programmer but totally new to C++. I'm using GLFW 3 and Horde3D in Xcode 5 on OS X 10.5.

I've followed the basic tutorials of GLFW and Horde3D. I'm able to create a window, make it the current context, and apparently a simple game loop is running fine, including `h3dRender( cam )`. But all I get is a black window. Any insight as to the step (or entire concept) I'm missing?

Thank you! (code below)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <Horde3D.h>
#include <Horde3DUtils.h>

GLFWwindow* window;
H3DNode model = 0, cam = 0;
int winWidth = 640, winHeight = 480;
float fps = 24;
static float t = 0;
bool running = false;

bool initWindow();
bool initGame();
void gameLoop();
void errorListener( int, const char* );
void windowCloseListener( GLFWwindow* );

int main(void)
{
    glfwSetErrorCallback( errorListener );

    if ( !initWindow() ) return -1;
    if ( !initGame() ) return -1;

    running = true;
    while ( running )
    {
        gameLoop();
    }

    h3dRelease();
    glfwDestroyWindow( window );
    glfwTerminate();
    exit( EXIT_SUCCESS );
}

bool initWindow()
{
    if ( !glfwInit() ) return -1;

    window = glfwCreateWindow( winWidth, winHeight, "Hello World", NULL, NULL );
    if ( !window )
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    glfwSetWindowCloseCallback( window, windowCloseListener );
    glfwMakeContextCurrent( window );
    glfwSwapInterval( 0 );

    return true;
}

bool initGame()
{
    if ( !h3dInit() ) return false;

    H3DRes pipeRes = h3dAddResource( H3DResTypes::Pipeline, "standard.pipeline", 0 );
    H3DRes modelRes = h3dAddResource( H3DResTypes::SceneGraph, "character.scene.xml", 0 );
    H3DRes animRes = h3dAddResource( H3DResTypes::Animation, "walk.anim.xml", 0 );
    h3dutLoadResourcesFromDisk( "" );

    model = h3dAddNodes( H3DRootNode, modelRes );
    h3dSetupModelAnimStage( model, 0, animRes, 0, "", false );

    H3DNode light = h3dAddLightNode( H3DRootNode, "Light 1", 0, "LIGHTING", "SHADOWMAP" );
    h3dSetNodeTransform( light, 0, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1 );
    h3dSetNodeParamF( light, H3DLight::RadiusF, 0, 50.0f );

    cam = h3dAddCameraNode( H3DRootNode, "Camera", pipeRes );

    h3dSetNodeParamI( cam, H3DCamera::ViewportXI, 0 );
    h3dSetNodeParamI( cam, H3DCamera::ViewportYI, 0 );
    h3dSetNodeParamI( cam, H3DCamera::ViewportWidthI, winWidth );
    h3dSetNodeParamI( cam, H3DCamera::ViewportHeightI, winHeight );
    h3dSetupCameraView( cam, 45.0f, ( float ) winWidth / winHeight, 0.5f, 2048.0f );
    h3dResizePipelineBuffers( pipeRes, winWidth, winHeight );

    return true;
}

void gameLoop ()
{
    t = t + 10.f * ( 1/ fps );
    h3dSetModelAnimParams( model, 0, t, 1.0f );
    h3dSetNodeTransform( model, t * 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1 );
    h3dRender( cam );
    h3dFinalizeFrame();
    glfwSwapBuffers( window );
    glfwPollEvents();
}

void errorListener( int error, const char* description )
{
    fputs( description, stderr );
}

void windowCloseListener( GLFWwindow* window )
{
    running = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not able to view anything because the resources have not been loaded for your application. You need to specify the directory path which holds the resources(resources like character.scene.xml, walk.anim.xml etc.) as the an argument to the  `h3dutLoadResourcesFromDisk()`